# Microsoft Bot Framework : SigninCard not showing in telegram

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, botframework

I tried create Telegram bot client with Microsoft Bot Framework, when I create signincard with this framework, signincard created successfully and I can see buttons in Microsoft Bot Emulator but when I publish to server and test it with Telegram, signincard not showing in bot, please tell me how to fix it.

code :

```
            Activity reply = null;
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), "", "");

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {                    
                if (activity.Text == "/start")
                {
                    reply = activity.CreateReply($"Welcome, please select an option");
                    reply.Recipient = activity.From;
                    reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
                    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

                    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
                    var helpAction = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Image = "",
                        Title = "Get Menu",
                        Type = "imBack",
                        Value = "help"
                    };

                    var contactAction = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Image = "",
                        Title = "Contact Us",
                        Type = "imBack",
                        Value = "contact"
                    };
                    cardButtons.Add(helpAction);
                    cardButtons.Add(contactAction);

                    var sc = new SigninCard()
                    {
                        Buttons = cardButtons,
                        Text = ""
                    };

                    Attachment attach = sc.ToAttachment();
                    reply.Attachments.Add(attach);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **sign-in** card type must be "**signin**", and the value should be **url** instead of string

working code:

```
replyActivity.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

var cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
var plButton = new CardAction
{
    Value = auth.SessionUrl,
    Type = "signin",
    Title = "Connect"
};
cardButtons.Add(plButton);
var plCard = new SigninCard("You need to authorize to use Quick Book feature", cardButtons);

var plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
replyActivity.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
replyActivity.Text = "Should go to conversation, sign-in card";
```

screenshot:

[image]